# Array of Queues in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, queue

Probably a very dumb question, but I want to create an array of queues in vb.net - so I can reference each queue with an index:

eg

```
commandQueue(1).enqueue("itemtext")

commandQueue(2).enqueue("othertext")
```

where commandQueue(1) refers to a separate queue than commandQueue(2)

I've got all tangled up trying to define an object array and put queues in.

Yes of course I can do it with old fashioned arrays, pointers etc, doing the management by hand, but this seemed so much more elegant...

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with this solution?

```
Dim commandQueue As Queue(Of T)()
```

There's nothing “old fashioned” about this solution. However, dynamic memories might sometimes be better suited:

```
Dim commandQueue As New List(Of Queue(Of T))()
```

In both cases, you need to initialize each queue before using it! In the case of an array, the array has to be initialized as well:

```
' Either directly: '
Dim commandQueue(9) As Queue(Of T)
' or, arguably clearer because the array length is mentioned explicitly: '
Dim commandQueue As Queue(Of T)() = Nothing ' `= Nothing` prevents compiler warning '
Array.Resize(commandQueue, 10)
```